# Google Plus Signin and Over-The-Air Install not working?

Tags: google-plus

I've managed to build the PhotoHunt ( https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/android-app-installs) demo app but did not manage to get the sign-in to display the Google Play popup in order to download the Android app.

I've created my api project, gave it 2 client ids, one for the web app ( hosted here: http://getnowtesting.appspot.com/ ) and one for the Android app ( properly got the package name and certificate fingerprint. ) and the signin has the apppackagename properly attached.

For more info, I have the app already on the play store, the test account has a device attached that can run the app, and the app is not already installed on the device.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Is the feature working for someone?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The likely reason is that your app has not yet exceeded Google's quality threshold for becoming available for over-the-air installs. This quality threshold is not published, but is intended to ensure that only quality apps that have sufficient reviews, ratings, and installs are able to be pushed to devices.

https://developers.google.com/+/features/play-installs

Edit: Apps also must be free. In your case, that appears true.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not the case, as I've tried with an app that has many positive reviews. I'm inclined to believe that this Over-The-Air Install feature does not function as designed or I'm not using it properly.

Comment: It doesn't work to use someone else's package name on your button. The package name's are tied to a client ID.

Editing my answer to cover another possible issue.

Comment: Hello again. I've tried the sample that Google Plus team set up during their demo and now it doesn't work for them either. http://711d8b8e21bf.appspot.com/

Comment: That sample doesn't exist in the Google Play Store, that should fail. See https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.plus.samples.photohunt

Comment: hey BrettJ, thanks for the info... if you could mention that beta testers for a particular app are offered the over-the-air install to their own app, that'd be great. I don't really know where else to suggest this to Google.

Comment: We've heard that feature request already and the team is aware of the need.